# Elastic Search with faceted GeoPoint search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

What would be the query structure for elastic search to search facted locations?

I have a products database with associated locations. I want to search products by name, and location. I feel as though the correct location would be faceted search on locations.

What would be the query structure for this? Thanks!

(If you can show the example using the Tire gem for Rails I'll name my first child after you)

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
{
"query" : {
    "field" : { "text" : "restaurant" }
},
"facets" : {
    "geo1" : {
        "geo_distance" : {
            "pin.location" : {
                "lat" : 40,
                "lon" : -70
            },
            "ranges" : [
                { "to" : 10 },
                { "from" : 10, "to" : 20 },
                { "from" : 20, "to" : 100 },
                { "from" : 100 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

More here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2010/08/16/geo_location_and_search.html